# How to compute the sample update error?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

In the book **Reinforcement Learning An Introduction，Chapter 8.5**，there is an example that compares the efficiency of expected and sample updates:[image]

According to the author, "In this case, sample updates reduce the error
according to $\sqrt{\frac{b-1}{bt}}$ where $t$ is the number of sample updates that have been performed (assuming sample averages, i.e., $\alpha = \frac{1}{t}$."
I just wonder how to  compute the sample-update error(i.e.,How to get the formula $\sqrt{\frac{b-1}{bt}}$?